# Import Error: Python Unit Tests, on Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins

I have a few unit tests, which I wrote in Python 2.7. (On PyCharm)
All of these test run locally just fine. However, I am trying to run them on Jenkins automation server.

The problem is that when running on Jenkins I get: 
 "ImportError: Failed to import test module: test_one." 
I believe this is because an import within that test, which is located a few levels above in the hierarchy. (See hierarchy below)

- modules

  - jira

    - jira_module #File to be imported
- unit_tests

  - test_one

So, test_one contains the line "import modules.jira.jira_module as jm"

But the command line on Jenkins apparently doesn't like the path using dots. Does anyone know how to solve this issue? I've attempted using runpy - run_path, but that did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

For this line to work

```
import modules.jira.jira_module as jm
```

module package `modules` must be located within `PYTHONPATH`.

The right approach is that the root directory (which contains `modules` and `unit_tests` folders) would the one in which you start the tests. Usually in the project root a bootstrap file is created to run the tests (`runtests.py` or `runtests.sh` or similar).

If you don't know how to this, or find this difficult, you could tweak the paths adding the root folder to `sys.path` in `test_one.py`. But this is ugly and not right.